# создание класса карта и колода

Tags: python

Нужно создать класс карты, чтобы представить игровую карту в пирамиде.
Создать класс Колода для представления колоды карт в пирамиде.
Вот я написал код, но преподаватель говорит что надо реализовать этот класс с использованием шаблонов проектирования, помогите пожалуйста.

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = ['в™*', 'в™Ј', 'в™Ґ', 'в™¦']
        self.cards = []
        self.cart = []
        for card_num in range(0, 52):
            r = str(card_num % 13)
            if r == '0':
                r = 'K'
            if r == '1':
                r = 'A'
            if r == '12':
                r = 'Q'
            if r == '11':
                r = 'J'
            index = int((card_num / 13) % 13)
            self.cards.append((r, self.list[index]))

    def draw(self):
        next = self.cards.pop(random.randint(0, len(self.cards) - 1))
        return next

    def deck(self):
        c = Card()
        for i in range(0, 52):
            self.cart.append(c.draw())


        print(30*' ',self.cart[0])
        print(25*' ',self.cart[1:3])
        print(20*' ',self.cart[4:7])
        print(15*' ',self.cart[7:11])
        print(10*' ',self.cart[11:16])
        print(5*' ',self.cart[16:22])
        print(self.cart[23:30])
        print(30 * "---")
        print(self.cart[31:])

c = Card()
c.deck()
```

Колода должна быть синглетоном. Также колода имеет реализовывать итератор, что выдавать текущие карты. Также насколько я понял, то карты имеют розпихатись по строкам пирамиды, то каждая строка может быть создан через фабрику классов. А вывод каждой строки через декоратор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колоду и карту следует сделать двумя отдельными классами. Синглтон в классе можно реализовать, переопределив специальный метод `__new__`. Итератор можно реализовать, определив специальный метод `__iter__`

Вот эту часть я вообще не понял: "карты имеют розпихатись по строкам пирамиды, то каждая строка может быть создан через фабрику классов. А вывод каждой строки через декоратор." Если сможете внятно сформулировать, что вам нужно, я смогу дописать код.

```
from random import shuffle


CARD_VALUES = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']
CARD_SUITS = ['\u2665', '\u2666', '\u2663', '\u2660']

class Card:

  def __init__(self, number):
    self.suit, self.value = divmod(number, 13)

  def __str__(self):
    return CARD_SUITS[self.suit] + CARD_VALUES[self.value]

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)


class Deck:

  singleton = None

  def __new__(cls):
    if cls.singleton:
      return cls.singleton
    else:
      obj = super().__new__(cls)
      cls.singleton = obj
      return obj

  def __init__(self):
    self.cards = [Card(i) for i in range(52)]
    self.shuffle()

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.cards)

  def shuffle(self):
    shuffle(self.cards)

  def __str__(self):
    return 'Deck{}'.format(self.cards)

# Демнострация поведения синглтона:
# видно, что оба экземпляра класса являются одним и тем же объектом

deck1 = Deck()
deck2 = Deck()

print(deck1)
print(deck2)

print(deck1 is deck2)

# Демонстрация работы итератора

print([card for card in deck1])
```

Comment: карты имеют расходиться по строкам пирамиды  каждая строка пирамиды должна быть абстрактной фарбрикою а вывод каждой строки должен быть через декоратор

Comment: @drako08, понятнее не стало. У вас есть чётко сформулированный текст задания?

Comment: создать класс карты, чтобы представить игровую карту в пирамиде. Создать класс Колода для представления колоды карт в пирамиде